# How to check what kernel grub will attempt to load on next boot

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I know that `uname -r` will show the current loaded kernel, but how exactly do I see what kernel grub will attempt to load on the next bootup?

I'm assuming it's in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` however I see lots of different kernels listed there (assuming for the grub menu options). Which one in there is grub choosing to load on next boot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the first menu entry is chosen, unless you select another one at boot time when the menu is displayed. 
You can also choose the next entry to be used in /etc/grub.d/00_header.